# How to access html cell objects (get & set cell values)

Tags: html, object, cell

I have set up an html table populated with 16 rows and all the cells are populated with sample data. I'm trying to access the table cells as objects via jQuery onclick event without success.

I have looked at all possible answers on StackOverflow but but of them work for me.

```
$("th #trash").click(function(event) {
   var tableRow = $('#tblStOrders').find('tbody').find('tr');

   //This displays 16, which is correct
   console.log(tableRow.length);

   //This loop shows the i index correctly but cell values display as undefined.

   for (var i = 0; i < tableRow.length; i++) {
     var cellValue = $(tableRow[i]).find('td:eq(0)').html();
     console.log(i, cellValue);
   }
   event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: can you show the table code in html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems to work perfectly. See below, it does return all 16 cell values.

```js
var tableRow = $('#tblStOrders').find('tbody').find('tr');

   //This displays 16, which is correct
   console.log(tableRow.length);

   //This loop shows the i index correctly but cell values display as undefined.

   for (var i = 0; i < tableRow.length; i++) {
     var cellValue = $(tableRow[i]).find('td:eq(0)').html();
     console.log(i, cellValue);
   }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tblStOrders">
    <tbody>
    <tr><td>1</td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td>2</td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td>3</td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td>4</td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td>5</td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td>6</td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td>7</td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td>8</td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td>9</td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td>10</td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td>11</td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td>12</td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td>13</td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td>14</td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td>15</td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td>16</td><td></td></tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

The only reason I can think of for your code returning undefined is that for some reason your rows are missing `<td></td>` cells? Are you generating the table dynamically?

Comment: You are right, I had accidentally used <th></th> instead of <td></td> for the data rows. I have spent so many hour trying to understand what I was doing wrong. THANK YOU!!!

Comment: @NormanRorke You're most welcome. If the answer worked for you please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: Done. Apologies for not having done it immediately. I'm new to the forum.